# Unit test a very simple method, but failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I have a simple `School` class which defines a `init` method:

```
@implementation School
- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // call class method of MyHelper class
        if ([MyHelper isWeekend]) {
           [MyHelper doSomething];
        }
    }
}
@end
```

(`MyHelper` is a class contains only class methods, the `isWeekend` is a class method returns a boolean value)

I use [OCMock](http://ocmock.org/reference/) to unit test this simple `init` method:

```
- (void)testInit {
    // mock a school instance
    id schoolMock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:[[School alloc] init]];

    // mock class MyHelper
    id MyHelperMock = OCMStrictClassMock([MyHelper class]);
    // stub class method 'isWeekend()' to return true
    OCMExpect([MyHelperMock isWeekend]).andReturn(true);

    // run init method
    [schoolMock init];

    // verify
    OCMVerify([MyHelperMock isWeekend]);

}
```

But when run it, I get error:

`OCMockObject(MyHelper): Method isWeekend was not invoked.` why?

Answer (score 0):

You've created a mock for the `MyHelper` class, but this isn't going to be used within the implementation of your `School` object. You'd only get the mocked response if you wrote `[MyHelperMock isWeekend]`, which you can't do inside the initialiser without rewriting it for tests.

To make your `School` class more testable you should be passing in any dependencies on initialisation. For example, you could pass in the `isWeekend` value as part of the initialiser, instead of obtaining it inside the method, or pass in the class object (`MyHelper` or `MyHelperMock`).

It's worth noting that finding certain classes or methods difficult to test because of things like this is often a good indicator that your code isn't structured very well.